# Young Oom Sarel Peach tree with yellowing leaves

Tags: trees, leaves, peaches

Please can someone help me? I have recently purchased an **Oom Sarel Peach** (South Africa). It is still in its Nursery bag until I re-pot it into a larger growing bag in a few weeks.

I have given it some Seagrow fish emulsion plant food, once, about 2 weeks ago. I need to give it again tonight or in the next few days. I am having to water it a little nearly every night (about 1/3rd of a litre), as the top 1.5" of soil is dry/barely moist and the bottom drainage holes are also dry.
Are the yellowing leaves a case of overwatering? Should I only water once or twice a week rather?

It also came with a few peaches growing on it already.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Peaches are very susceptible to over watering. Mostly your addition of too much water may be because the pots are really too small for the trees to live comfortably. Bigger pots would allow for a larger volume of compost, some to accommodate the roots and some as a buffer reserve of water and access to more nutrients. That way you can cut back on the watering, maintaining a sufficiently moist environment without being tempted to give too much. Boost the pot size and fill with compost, water to a comfortable level, then weigh the whole plant together with the pot and when watering make sure you do not exceed that weight - it's one way of making sure you do not add too much.